# Given a string and integer n, split the string at n characters, and print as follows:

Tags: code-golf, string, source-layout

Given a string and integer n, split the string at n character, and print as follows: 
Ex)

`laptop 3` should print `lap top`

`laptop 2` should print `la pt op` (see how it splits the string at every 2nd char)

Special cases:

`laptop 0` should print `laptop` (since we split at every 0th char, thus none)

`laptop 9` should print `laptop` (since length of laptop < 9, so no splitting)

`bob 2` should print `bo b` (we split at the `o` (2nd char), but then there aren't enough characters after, so we just leave as is`

You may assume n >= 0

Comment: What does "print it together" mean? Print with spaces in between, or just print it in any clear format?

Comment: @ETHproductions in the format I have specified, sorry for the confusing

Comment: May we print more spaces after the string output?

Comment: @dzaima no. thats why I made it so that if you do not enough characters after splitting, you just print the rest of the string (no extra spaces after the rest of the string has been printed)

Comment: Not a duplicate: This one is only part of the other challenge - and it allows builtins.

Comment: Can I print linebreaks instead of spaces?

Answer (score 2):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 7 bytes

```
òVªLl)¸
```

[Test it online!](http://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.5&code=8laqTGwpuA==&input=ImxhcHRvcCIgMg==)

#### Explanation

```
            Implicit: U, V = inputs
UòV   )     Split U into slices of length V.
   ªLl      If V is 0, instead use 100! (roughly 9.3326e+157).
       ¸    Join with spaces.
            Implicit: output result of last expression
```

9.3326e+157 is far larger than JavaScript's max string size of 9.0072e+15, so this will work for any input.

Answer (score 2):

## JavaScript, <s>54</s> 47 bytes

```
s=>n=>n?eval(`s.match(/.{1,${n}}/g)`).join` `:s
```

```js
f=
s=>n=>n?eval(`s.match(/.{1,${n}}/g)`).join` `:s


console.log(
    f('laptop')(0),
    f('laptop')(1),
    f('laptop')(2),
    f('laptop')(3),
    f('laptop')(4)
)
```

Answer (score 1):

## PHP, 48 bytes

```php
[,$s,$n]=$argv;echo$n?chunk_split($s,$n," "):$s;
```

Run with `-r`.

Answer (score 1):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly),  <s>7</s>  5 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
sW⁹?K
```

A full program printing the result (or a dyadic link returning a list of characters).

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/784/FHjTnvv////K@UkFpTkFyj9NwIA)**

#### How?

```
sW⁹?K - Main link: list of characters, a; number, n
   ?  - if:
  ⁹   -       chain's right argument = n (0 is not truthy, positive integers are)
s     - then: split a into chunks of length n (overflow kept like the challenge requires)
 W    - else: wrap a in a list
    K - join with spaces (the wrapped list becomes depth 1 again with no spaces)
      - implicit print
```

Comment: When I first learned Jelly, I didn't understand how `?` could really be useful, but that's twice now in 24 hours... Dennis really can do no wrong ;)

Comment: So each conditional clause can only have one atom?

Comment: @totallyhuman they could be: single atoms; together a [multi-chain-link](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Tutorial#5multi-chain-links) (individually just called "chains"); [referenced-links](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Tutorial#61referring-to-links); or [compound-links](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Tutorial#61referring-to-links).

Answer (score 0):

## [CJam](https://sourceforge.net/p/cjam), 11 bytes

```
q~:X{X/S*}&
```

[**Try it online!**](https://tio.run/##S85KzP3/v7DOKqI6Qj9Yq1bt/3@lpPwkJQUjAA)

#### How it works

```
q~           e# Read all input and evaluate. Pushes the string and the number n
  :X         e# Store n in variable X
    {    }&  e# If top of the stack (number n) is nonzero, run this block
     X       e# Push N again
      /      e# Split into pieces that long. Last piece may be shorter
       S     e# Push space
        *    e# Join using spaces
             e# Implicitly display
```

Comment: wow i dont think it can get shorter then this

Comment: @ETHproductions Aww. Thanks!

Comment: @ETHproductions Corrected

Answer (score 0):

### Haskell, 33 bytes

```
import Data.List
s!n=chunksOf n s
```

Comment: If not explicitly specified, the order of inputs can be arbitrary, so just `chunksOf` is a valid submission. In case the list has to be the first argument `flip chunksOf` is a shorter way.

Answer (score 0):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>76</s> <s>67</s> 56 bytes

*-13 bytes thanks to ETHproductions and notjagan.*

```python
lambda s,n:n and[s[i:i+n]for i in range(0,len(s),n)]or s
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DckxDoAgEATAr1wHRAqjHYkvUYszgl6CCwEaX49OO/ltd8LUw7L1yM9xMlULB2Kca13FyYA9pEJCAiqMy@vRRg9djYXZ/6k9F0GjoFXk3FJWlmbTPw)

### Regex solution, 56 bytes

```python
lambda s,n:re.findall('.{1,%i}'%n or len(s),s)
import re
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##BcFBCoAgEADAe6/YS6ggQnUL@kkXQyVhXZfVS0Rvtxl@@l1pHek4B/pyBQ/N0i7RpUzBI2rl3sXO@VMzQRXASLoZ28yUC1fpIHGwZOqQtELPvbKysJnxAw)

Comment: Could you remove the `and n`?

Comment: @ETHproductions Yes, I can! Don't know what I was thinking. o0

Comment: I think you can do `s,n=input();print n and[s[i:i+n]for i in range(0,len(s),n)]or s` for 63 (note: I have not tested this)

Comment: @ETHproductions I was just about to suggest [the same](https://tio.run/##dcqxDoIwFEbh3ae4YeqNHQhOkPgkyHAbKNyk/G3aLj59dTRR1@@c9KxHxND8/dGCnG4VKhYTSLDOZdZJr1h8zKSkoCzYN9PbsMEUtuDlXUpLWVGNN12QVGPqLA3Ml2@9faqL7u84/tSeub0A) for 56 bytes.

Comment: Oh, you guys ninja'd me. >< Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

## Mathematica, 114 bytes

```
d=StringRiffle;If[#2>(s=StringLength@#)||#2==0,#,k=d@StringPartition[#,#2];If[#2<=s/2,k,d[{k,StringDrop[#,#2]}]]]&
```

Answer (score 0):

## [QBIC](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0B0R1Jgqp8Gg4cVJCZkRkdEthZDQ), 27 bytes

```
_L;|~:|\b=a][1,a,b|?_sA,c,b
```

### Explanation

```
_L;|        set a as the length of A$ (input from cmd line)
~:|         IF b (input num from cmd line) is anything but 0 THEN (empty)
\b=a        ELSE (b==0) set b to the full length of A$
]           END IF
[1,a,b|     FOR c = 1; c <= LEN(A$); c = c + b
?_sA,c,b    PRINT a substring of A$, starting at c, running for b chars.
            NEXT is auto-added at EOF
```